# How can I "find and insert" into a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to upload a few stats in an database, how can I take something out of an callback and put it in an variable to simplify this?

Code:

```
csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, function(ranking) {
                console.log(ranking);
            });
```

Result (ranking):

```
Got handled GC message PlayersProfile
{ my_current_event_teams: [],
  my_current_event_stages: [],
  account_id: xxxxxxx,
  ongoingmatch: null,
  global_stats: null,
  penalty_seconds: null,
  penalty_reason: null,
  vac_banned: null,
  ranking:
   { account_id: xxxxxxx,
     rank_id: 16,
     wins: 1081,
     rank_change: null },
  commendation: { cmd_friendly: 23, cmd_teaching: 24, cmd_leader: 24 },
  medals:
   { display_items_defidx:
      [ 969, 4551, 1377, 970, 1358, 4354, 1340, 1338, 1331, 1329, 1030, 874 ],
     medal_team: null,
     medal_combat: null,
     medal_weapon: null,
     medal_global: null,
     medal_arms: null,
     featured_display_item_defidx: 969 },
  my_current_event: null,
  my_current_team: null,
  survey_vote: null,
  activity: null,
  player_level: 19,
  player_cur_xp: 327682724,
  player_xp_bonus_flags: null }
```

So as an example I want to put the `rank_id: 16` in an var (ex. `var rank = 16;`) so I cant just use `"UPDATE Users SET Rank='rank'"`

Comment: I think the way you ask this question is not very clear. However, from your callback you should be able to access the part of the data you need as `ranking.ranking.rank_id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rank = ranking.ranking.rank_id;
```

Comment: Thats actually so simple, but still don't make sense to me...
Why do I need 2x ranking? //Edit: nvm, got it...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing callback function to this requestPlayersProfile,
so everything you need is just to call db from that "doSomething" function. All data you need will be in "ranking" variable.

```js
function doSomething(ranking) {
  // do everything you want with that data here
}

csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, doSomething);
```

Comment: I dont understand this, I hate javascript ._.
Thought I can just find something in the callback (like in php) and put it in an var...

Comment: you could do this inside doSomething function, but what you want to do next with that variable?

Comment: SherylHohman's  answer was pretty good. I want to put it in an database